# Guardar datos en array mediante JQuery

Tags: jquery, array

¡Buenas!

Estoy intentando crear una especie de formulario.

La cosa es que el usuario hace click sobre un botón y le aparecen diferentes campos a rellenar (estos campos serán inputs de tipo texto* ).

Una vez rellenado, hace click sobre un nuevo botón que ha aparecido junto a los **input text** para guardar.

¿Como hago para meter estos campos en un `array`?¿He de tener el `array` creado previamente, o lo puedo crear al momento? La idea sería tenerlos en un `array` para luego acceder a este y coger los datos que me interesen trabajar/mostrar.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // JS para crear rutinas estilo POWER

  $('#Anyadir-Rutina-btn').click(function() {

    // Hacemos aparecer la ventana modal donde rellenamos formulario.
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').css({
      'display': 'flex',
      'height': 'auto',
      'width': '80%'
    });

    // Creamos las variables donde se describen todos los elementos del formulario
    var titulo1 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Titulo 1" id="Titulo1" />';
    var titulo2 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Título 2" id="Titulo2" />';
    var guardarModalBtn = '<input type="button" value="Guardar" id="Guardar-modal-btn" />';

    // Insertamos los elementos para que el usuario rellene el formulario
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append(titulo1);
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append(titulo2);
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append(guardarModalBtn);


    // Botón guardar. Guarda y muestra los datos escritos en el formulario.
    $('#Guardar-modal-btn').click(function() {

      alert("Ahora debería guardar");

    });

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Kiitos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres acceder a los valores del `array` en cualquier parte del documento **JS** después de haberlo llenado entonces debes crear la variable como global, y luego por medio del método `.push()` podrás añadir todos los valores que quieras al `array`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // JS para crear rutinas estilo POWER
  var valores = []; //Declaramos el Array

  $('#Anyadir-Rutina-btn').click(function() {

    // Hacemos aparecer la ventana modal donde rellenamos formulario.
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').css({
      'display': 'flex',
      'flex-direction':'column',
      'height': 'auto',
      'width': '80%'
    });

    // Creamos las variables donde se describen todos los elementos del formulario
    var titulo1 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Titulo 1" id="Titulo1" class="form-control"/>';
    var titulo2 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Título 2" id="Titulo2" class="form-control"/>';
    var guardarModalBtn = '<input type="button" value="Guardar" id="Guardar-modal-btn" class="btn btn-primary"/>';

    // Insertamos los elementos para que el usuario rellene el formulario
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append(titulo1);
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append(titulo2);
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append(guardarModalBtn);


    // Botón guardar. Guarda y muestra los datos escritos en el formulario.
    $('#Guardar-modal-btn').click(function() {

      var Titulo1 = $("#Titulo1").val();
      var Titulo2 = $("#Titulo2").val();
      
      valores.push(Titulo1, Titulo2); // Llenamos el array con los datos
      
      console.log(valores);

    });

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button id="Anyadir-Rutina-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Añadir rutina</button>

<div id="Modal-Escribir-Rutina"></div>
```

Pero si lo que quieres es acceder a los datos aún después de refrescar la página entonces deberías usar [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // JS para crear rutinas estilo POWER
  $('#Anyadir-Rutina-btn').click(function() {

    // Hacemos aparecer la ventana modal donde rellenamos formulario.
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').css({
      'display': 'flex',
      'flex-direction':'column',
      'height': 'auto',
      'width': '80%'
    });

    // Creamos las variables donde se describen todos los elementos del formulario
    var titulo1 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Titulo 1" id="Titulo1" class="form-control"/>';
    var titulo2 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Título 2" id="Titulo2" class="form-control"/>';
    var guardarModalBtn = '<input type="button" value="Guardar" id="Guardar-modal-btn" class="btn btn-primary"/>';

    // Insertamos los elementos para que el usuario rellene el formulario
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append(titulo1);
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append(titulo2);
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append(guardarModalBtn);


    // Botón guardar. Guarda y muestra los datos escritos en el formulario.
    $('#Guardar-modal-btn').click(function() {

      var Titulo1 = $("#Titulo1").val();
      var Titulo2 = $("#Titulo2").val();
      
      localStorage.setItem('Titulo1', Titulo1); // Seteamos los items
      localStorage.setItem('Titulo2', Titulo2); // Seteamos los items
      
      console.log(localStorage.getItem('Titulo1')); // Obtenemos los items antes creados
      console.log(localStorage.getItem('Titulo2')); // Obtenemos los items antes creados
      
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button id="Anyadir-Rutina-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Añadir rutina</button>

<div id="Modal-Escribir-Rutina"></div>
```

Por razones de seguridad el snippet de SOes no permite ejecutar el **localStorage** pero si haces la prueba en tu entorno local debería de funcionarte.

Answer (score 0):

Todo depende de qué quieras hacer con el array: si lo vas a usar en otro momento, guárdalo en una variable declarada fuera de la función. Si lo vas a mostrar (y quizá enviarlo con AJAX a tu servidor) en este instante y no lo vas a volver a necesitar, basta con declararlo en la función y usarlo.

Comment: Pues la cosa es básicamente después mostrarlo en pantalla. Pero había pensado en guardarlos en un array porque esta página se emplea como un "diario", quiero decir que mañana tiene que aparecer lo que apunte mañana pero también recordar el contenido de hoy, y así sucesivamente. Otra idea sería escribir esto en un fichero externo e ir accediendo a él. ¿no? La verdad es que no se como afrontarlo.

Comment: Almacenarlo para sucesivas visitas... O usas `localstorage` (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), que almacena los datos en una memoria no perecedera gestionada por el navegador, o mejor, los almacenas en un servidor, en una base de datos, lo cual también es un problema completamente distinto.

Comment: Cada vez que abandonas la página, las variables se borran. O usas el localStorage o lo guardas en el servidor

Answer (score 0):

Buenas amigo espero esto te ayude saludos.

Para obtener los datos de los `input` usamos

```
var titulo1 = $("#titulo1").val()
var titulo2 = $("#titulo2").val()
```

y después lo único que hacemos es agregarlo al `objeto`

```
objeto = {
    titulo1:titulo1,
    titulo2:titulo2
  }
```

y listo ya tenemos los valores a enviar.

**Ejemplo Funcional**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // JS para crear rutinas estilo POWER

  $('#Anyadir-Rutina-btn').click(function() {
    // Hacemos aparecer la ventana modal donde rellenamos formulario.
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').css({
      'display': 'flex',
    });

    // Creamos las variables donde se describen todos los elementos del formulario
    var titulo1 = '<input id="titulo1" type="text" placeholder="Titulo 1" id="Titulo1" />';
    var titulo2 = '<input id="titulo2" type="text" placeholder="Título 2" id="Titulo2" />';
    var guardarModalBtn = '<input type="button" value="Guardar" id="Guardar-modal-btn" />';

    // Insertamos los elementos para que el usuario rellene el formulario
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append(titulo1);
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append(titulo2);
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append(guardarModalBtn);


    // Botón guardar. Guarda y muestra los datos escritos en el formulario.
    objeto = {}
    $('#Guardar-modal-btn').click(function() {
    alert("Ahora debería guardar");
      var titulo1 = $("#titulo1").val()
      var titulo2 = $("#titulo2").val()
      objeto = {
        titulo1:titulo1,
        titulo2:titulo2
      }
      
      console.log(objeto)
    });

  });

});
```

```css
#Modal-Escribir-Rutina {
  z-index;200;
  background:#fff;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  display:none;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#Modal-Escribir-Rutina input {
  padding:10px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Anyadir-Rutina-btn" type="button" name="button">Abrir Modal</button>
<div id="Modal-Escribir-Rutina">
</div>
```